# Dynamically creating a part when clicking the last part(Tab) in eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse, e4

I have created 2 parts in partstack. All parts uses same contribution uri. I need a 3rd part say "Add new part" (or tab) when clicked on, it has to create a new part dynamically and get arranged after the first 2 parts and then again the part "Add New Part" has to come at the end. So whenever "add New Part" is clicked it has to create new part.
The following code is added for the "Add New Part" part.

```
MPart part = partService.createPart("com.abc.xyz.project.partDescriptor.DynamicPart");
MPartStack stack = (MPartStack)modelService.find("com.abc.xyz.project.partstack.2", application);
     stack.getChildren().add(part);
            part.setLabel("New Dynamic Part");
    part.setVisible(true);
    part.setCloseable(true);
    partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);
```

Can any one please suggest me some ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Create your "Add new part" dynamically, like in the example (example is for input part):

```
MPartStack stack = (MPartStack) modelService.find("your.part.stack.id", application);
inputPart = MBasicFactory.INSTANCE.createInputPart();
inputPart.setContributionURI("bundleclass://your.plugin/your.class");
inputPart.setCloseable(isCloseable);
stack.getChildren().add(inputPart);
inputPart.setLabel("Add new part");
```

"bundleclass://your.plugin/your.class" is a reference to your class for the content of your part. It is like the "Class URI" field in a fragment editor. The code above adds a new tab to the part stack, but does not activate the part, so @Postconstruct method in the content class is not called. When the user clicks on the the tab, @Postconstruct method is called. There your can create a new part again.

Comment: But It is creating the part dynamically only once . I want to create the part dynamically everytime when the tab is clicked. It means the number of parts in the partstack has to increment by 1 more part when the "Add new Part" tab is clicked.

Comment: As I mentioned, if you insert this code into @Postconstruct method, you shall get a new tab every time the user clicks on the previously created tab.

Comment: This postConstruct method is called only once and not every time. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, only once, when the part is activated. But it creates a new part. And when a new part is activated, the @Postconstruct method is called again. And so on.

Comment: This only creates the most basic part with no menus or anything else. You should use a Part Descriptor as the template for a part.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Part Descriptor in the application model describing the part you want to add.

Use the `EPartService` to create the part:

```
MPart part = partService.createPart(part descriptor id);
```

Add the created part to a `MPartStack` defined on your application model, you can find the stack using the `EModelService`

```
MPartStack stack = (MPartStack)modelService.find(stack id, application);

stack.getChildren().add(part);
```

Make sure you check the `Multiple` option in the part description definition if you want to create multiple parts from the description.

Comment: In the PartDescriptor, should I add the part that I created or the class which creates the part dynamically? What properties of `PartDescriptor` should I configure?

Comment: A Part Descriptor is configured the same as a Part except you put it in the Part Descriptors section of the application model. It is a complete description of the part you want to create dynamically.

Comment: I have done all the steps as you have mentioned but only once the postconstruct is called and creates the dynamic part. The next time when I click on the part tab it is not creating any more new parts.

Comment: Show us your code. Make sure you check the `Multiple` option in the part descriptor definition.

Comment: I have checked the Multiple option in partDescriptor. I will add the code in the question.